# Is it Scientifically Rigorous to create a multimodal ML Model with data from multiple sources

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I'm attempting to create a multimodal machine learning model for disease diagnosis. However, I'm having quite a bit of difficulty finding public data sets with all the data I need.

For example, I need data on eye movement, facial expressions, and vocal fluctuations of an individual. I cannot find a data set that has all three of these for each individual. However, I am able to find separate data sets for each of these modalities, but each data set is from a completely different trial, and thus, is composed of different subjects.

Is it scientifically rigorous to collect each modality from a different data set/individual due to the lack of public data? If not, would you happen to have any advice on where/how I could find data?

Comment: Under some conditions it can be rigorous. These conditions although not easily expressible mathematically, reflect some basic "symmetries" the data should exhibit. For example a basic symmetry is that one subject from one dataset is similar to another subject of another dataset, then the two datasets can be merged. But defining this "similarity" is quite difficult. So, one checks the final result and if it is good, then chances are the criteria were met

Comment: You could try to create some sort of hierarchical Bayesian model (https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Eight_Schools), with different modalities of your data providing different likelihood functions for the same parameters. Would need more detail to say whether it would make sense

Comment: You may be interested in [statistical measures of heterogeneity of data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Study_heterogeneity) (as eg used in meta-analysis). These measures try to quantify exactly the similarity symmetries of the data (or studies) that need to be combined